# How to sync content title with "synchronize translations" module?

Tags: i18n-l10n

The synchronize translations module, part of the [Internationalization](https://www.drupal.org/project/i18n) module (i18n), allows us to sync content between two languages.

It works very well with node configurable and standard fields. But I can't configure it to sync also the node title.

[image]

Is there a way to force it to sync also the title, or any alternative to do this work?

Answer (score 0):

Possibly this is because titles do not get translated in a site using the [i18n](https://www.drupal.org/project/i18n) module. And that is most often because of the [Title](https://www.drupal.org/project/title) module that has not been enabled. From the module's project page (bold markup added here):

> After enabling the module as usual, visit the Manage fields page of the content type, taxonomy vocabulary or "comment type" which you wish to replace fields of and click the replace link. That's all.